# Python - Run telethon alongside Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, telethon

I'm looking to make a GUI telethon login and event listener using tkinter, but the GUI freeze when working with telethon, so I tried to use thread the first button is 'connect' which is connecting to telegram account, and 'send' button to start an event listening when a new message arrive but it's not working.

This is what I tried

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")
def refresh():
    print("update")
    root.update()
    root.after(1000, refresh)
def connect():
    global client
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash, flood_sleep_threshold=3)
    client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        client.send_code_request(phone)
        try:
            client.sign_in(phone, code=input(f'Enter the code: {phone} : '))
        except SessionPasswordNeededError:
            password = input("Enter 2fa password : ")
            client.sign_in(password=password)
    print(client.get_me())
async def handler(event):
    print(event)
def send():
    client.add_event_handler(handler, events.NewMessage)
    client.run_until_disconnected()
def click():
    print("Clicked!")

B = tkinter.Button(root, text="Connect", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=connect).start())
B.pack()
BB = tkinter.Button(root, text="Send", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=send).start())
BB.pack()
C = tkinter.Button(root, text="Hello", command=click)
C.pack()
refresh()
root.mainloop()
```

I've got the following error message when 'send' button pressed
`RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.`

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter does not really support `asyncio`, however, [there are workarounds](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/tree/v1/telethon_examples#guipy) (I recommend you check the linked example in full):

```py
async def main(interval=0.05):
    client = TelegramClient(SESSION, API_ID, API_HASH)
    try:
        await client.connect()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to connect', e, file=sys.stderr)
        return

    app = App(client)
    try:
        while True:
            # We want to update the application but get back
            # to asyncio's event loop. For this we sleep a
            # short time so the event loop can run.
            #
            # https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/33ecpl
            app.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except tkinter.TclError as e:
        if 'application has been destroyed' not in e.args[0]:
            raise
    finally:
        await app.cl.disconnect()
```